# Issues while enabling SSL on AWS Lightsail Load balancer and custom DNS CLoudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, cloudflare, amazon-lightsail

I have hosted a website using the LAMP stack in AWS Lightsail.
I am trying to enable SSL certificates for AWS Lightsail and custom DNS Cloudflare. I have already tried all the steps from 1-18 listed in the below article

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/verify-tls-ssl-certificate-using-dns-cname-https

Additionally, I added two CNAME records to my Cloudflare one for the root domain and the other for the www subdomain with a target as the Lightsail Load balancer and proxy status as proxied (tried DNS only).

I have tried all the possible combinations to make it work however, even after a couple of days status is showing as validation in progress.

Just wanted to check if anyone else had faced the same problem or if someone can suggest some troubleshooting steps or if I have missed anything?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Piyush

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a CAA record pointing to amazon.com in your Cloudflare DNS settings. Then create the TLS certificate from your Lightsail load balancer page.

If the above doesn't work I suggest you [install AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) and perform a `aws lightsail get-load-balancer-tls-certificates`. The response will show a failureReason field which will help you investigate. For example if the failureReason field returns "CAA_ERROR", then adding CAA records as I descibed above will solve the problem.

get-load-balancer-tls-certificates' documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/get-load-balancer-tls-certificates.html

Comment: After spending far too long debugging this same problem this answer was the key. Using the aws CLI as described above allow me to see what the error was which was NOT provided via the Lightsail UI.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I made a mistake while creating the CNAME record hence, it was not validated. After removing some additional fields from the string, worked!
Thanks